# What pages I need to stop crawling with Robots.txt

Tags: security, robots.txt

I developed a website and I make it online, but when I accessing to the logs files I get

> Message : 'No route matched.'    Stack Trace :
>   Core\Router->dispatch('robots.txt')

after a small search in google I found that the robot.txt file is more important for search engine (Google, Bing ... etc)

and it help to stop crawling some pages, but my questions is what I need to block with it ( which pages ) and how to stop some specific routes.

for example I have routes of administration always start with **/ad-dash**

Example : **/ad-dash/administration/index**

and when I make the search I see that some tutorial block the about, privacy, terms pages

My question is : I want to know which pages I need to stop crawling with Robots.txt ?

Comment: When you ask what you **need** to block, do you mean this in a SEO context? If yes, this question doesn’t seem to be on-topic here. Such questions can be asked on [webmasters.se].

Comment: It seems like you would know your requirements better than strangers on the Internet. I'm not sure what you're expecting us to tell you.